# API GET requests from Specific IP - Requests Library - Python

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, python-requests, pycurl

I'm looking to switch existing PHP code over to Python using the `Requests` library. The PHP code sends thousands of `GET` requests to an API to get needed data. The API limits `GET` requests to one every 6 seconds per IP. We have numerous IP addresses in order to pull faster. The faster the better in this case.

My question is is there a way to send the `GET` request from different IP addresses using the `Requests` library? I'm also open to using different libraries in Python or different methods to replace the IP addresses.

The current code makes use of `curl_multi_exec` with the `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` setting.

As far as code goes, I don't necessarily need code examples. I'm looking for more of a direction or option that will allow such features in Python. I would prefer not post code, but if its necessary, let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Requests supports setting the outbound interface.

There is a [Python cURL library](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/), though.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Amber. I appreciate the information you provided.